# Como Preencher meus campos através do meu Banco de Dados React-Native e (Firebase)

Tags: firebase, react, react-native, reactive-programming

Como Preencher meus TextInputs através do meus banco de dados para que o Usuário possa edita-los e inseri-los novamente(substituindo os antigos) por exemplo:(pegar meu email e senha que tenho no BD e colocar nesses TextsInputs para depois editar e como fazer pra enviar novamente pro BD), sou iniciante e por conta disso não sei como poderia realizar de forma correta...

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {View, Text, StyleSheet, Button, TextInput} from 'react-native';
import firebase from 'firebase';

export default class TelaLogin extends Component{

  constructor(props) {
          super(props);
          this.state = {
            cidadeINput:'',
            emailInput:'',
            estadoInput:'',
            nomeINput:'',
            senhaInput:'',
            usuarioInput:'',
          };

          let config = {
              apiKey: "AIzaSyBEAn6v3qKO8m7jEsO7JlpTAnsCvKSoevo",
              authDomain: "adote-ja.firebaseapp.com",
              databaseURL: "https://adote-ja.firebaseio.com/",
              projectId: "adote-ja",
              storageBucket: "adote-ja.appspot.com",
              messagingSenderId: "1081270881358"
          };
          firebase.initializeApp(config);

          this.inserirUsuario = this.inserirUsuario.bind(this);
  }

  inserirUsuario() {
      if( this.state.usuarioInput.length > 0 ){

          let usuarios = firebase.database().ref('usuarios');

          let chave = usuarios.push().key;

          usuarios.child(chave).set({
            usuario:this.state.usuarioInput,
            senha:this.state.senhaInput
          });
          alert("senha inserida")
      }
  }
        render(){
            return(
              <View style = {styles.container}>

                  <TextInput style={styles.input} placeholder="Usuário" onChangeText={(usuarioInput)=>this.setState({usuarioInput})} />

                  <TextInput style={styles.input} placeholder="Senha" onChangeText={(senhaInput)=>this.setState({senhaInput})} />

                    <Button title="inserir usuário" onPress={this.inserirUsuario} />
              </View>
            );
        }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({

  container:{
    flex: 1,
    marginTop: 20,
    padding: 20,
  },

  input:{
    height: 40,
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: '#FF0000',
  },
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Olá! Primeiro te recomendo não deixar dados de acesso a seu banco no Firebase exposto assim. 
Eu não conheço muito do Firebase, mas acredito que a chamada a API é algo assíncrono, então você poderia usar os métodos de vida do React pra pegar esses dados. Normalmente usamos o `componentDidMout(){}` onde é chamado após o componente ser chamado e aí você pode evoluir o Estado e isso vai refletir no seu componente text.

Baseando no primeiro post que você colocou a chamada ao Firebase e que o nome dos inputs sejam o nome dos seus campos no banco de dados, ficaria assim, logo abaixo do seu método construtor:

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {View, Text, StyleSheet, Button, TextInput} from 'react-native';
import firebase from 'firebase';

export default class TelaLogin extends Component{

  constructor(props) {
          super(props);
          this.state = {
            cidadeINput:'',
            emailInput:'',
            estadoInput:'',
            nomeINput:'',
            senhaInput:'',
            usuarioInput:'',
          };

          let config = {
              apiKey: "AIzaSyBEAn6v3qKO8m7jEsO7JlpTAnsCvKSoevo",
              authDomain: "adote-ja.firebaseapp.com",
              databaseURL: "https://adote-ja.firebaseio.com/",
              projectId: "adote-ja",
              storageBucket: "adote-ja.appspot.com",
              messagingSenderId: "1081270881358"
          };
          firebase.initializeApp(config);

          this.inserirUsuario = this.inserirUsuario.bind(this);
  }
// Notei que você recebe só o nome na função, poderia retornar todos os dados tbm se necessário
  componentDidMount() {
    let data;
    firebase.database().ref("nome").on('value', (snapshot)=> data = snapshot.val() //poderia já setar o state aqui.)
    this.setstate({
            usuario: data,
    }) 
}


  inserirUsuario() {
      if( this.state.usuarioInput.length > 0 ){

          let usuarios = firebase.database().ref('usuarios');

          let chave = usuarios.push().key;

          usuarios.child(chave).set({
            usuario:this.state.usuarioInput,
            senha:this.state.senhaInput
          });
          alert("senha inserida")
      }
  }
        render(){
        const { usuario, senha } = this.state; //usando a desestruturação
            return(
              <View style = {styles.container}>

                  <TextInput style={styles.input} value={usuario} placeholder="Usuário" onChangeText={(usuarioInput)=>this.setState({usuarioInput})} />

                  <TextInput style={styles.input} placeholder="Senha" 
value={senha} onChangeText={(senhaInput)=>this.setState({senhaInput})} />

                    <Button title="inserir usuário" onPress={this.inserirUsuario} />
              </View>
            );
        }
}
```

Veja que inseri o atributo **value** dentro TextInput.
Detalhe também é que não sei exatamente o retorno dos dados que vem do firebase então coloquei ali como eu acredito que seja.

Comment: Amigo, não era bem esse problema que eu tenho, eu preciso trazer os textsinputs preenchido por dados do meu BD para que o usuario possa edita-lo dps e clicar em atualizar

Comment: Sim, para preencher com os dados que vem do banco, o componente precisa estar montado primeiro e só depois disso você seta o state com os dados que vem do componente. Por isso você usa o `ComponentDidMount` para fazer isso. coloque sua função de buscar os dados dentro do compomentDidMout.

Comment: amigo vc poderia me dar um exemplo com o código para eu ver/

Comment: escreva um exemplo em código fazendo favor de como seria

Comment: Alterei minha primeira resposta colocando o componentDidMount. Essa é a resposta, só tem que ver se o método que você usa pra chamar o Firebase está certo e se os dados que são retornados são esses mesmo. É possível que talvez tenha que inserir um Async/Await no método.